# Reordering levels of a factor in R data.frame

Tags: r, sorting, levels

This is a simple example of what I'm facing. I've my factor levels `B-1, B-2, B-9, B-10, B-11` and want to arrange them in above given order. Here I can easily rearrange the levels, however, in my data I do have complex structure and would like to do it through some coding. I wonder how to arrange these factor levels in their logical order.

```
set.seed(12345)
f <- rep(c("B-1", "B-2", "B-9", "B-10", "B-11"), each=3)
Y <- runif(n=15, min=100, max=1000)
df <- data.frame(f, Y)


levels(df$f)
[1] "B-1"  "B-10" "B-11" "B-2"  "B-9"

library(gtools)
mixedsort(df$f)

[1] B-1  B-1  B-1  B-10 B-10 B-10 B-11 B-11 B-11 B-2  B-2  B-2  B-9  B-9  B-9 

Levels: B-1 B-10 B-11 B-2 B-9

df2 <- df[mixedorder(df$f), ]


df3 <- within(df, 
         Position <- factor(f, 
                          levels=names(sort(table(f), 
                                            decreasing=TRUE))))

levels(df3$Position)
[1] "B-1"  "B-10" "B-11" "B-2"  "B-9"
```

### Edited

Now I can have the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34341923/707145) which was closed immediately as I posted it. Thanks @akrun for your help.

Comment: is that the only reason you're using the gtools package? `levels(df$f) <- levels(df$f)[order(as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', levels(df$f))))]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can specify the `levels` as the `mixedsort`ed `levels` of the 'f' column.

```
 df$f <- factor(df$f, levels=mixedsort(levels(df$f), decreasing=TRUE))
 levels(df$f)
 #[1] "B-1"  "B-2"  "B-9"  "B-10" "B-11"
```

Or as suggested by @Ben Bolker, a variation would be

```
 df <- transform(df,f=factor(f,levels=mixedsort(levels(f), 
          decreasing=TRUE)))
```

and I guess `-` is interpreted as `minus` sign as @Gregor suggested in the comments.

Comment: this works for me, but I am quite puzzled why `decreasing=TRUE` is necessary to get the values sorted in what is (to me at least) *increasing* order (B-1 up to B-11) ??

Comment: or `df <- transform(f,f=factor(f),levels=mixedsort(levels(f), decreasing=TRUE))`

Comment: I think the hyphens are interepreted as minus signs, making all the numbers negative to `mixedsort`.

Comment: @BenBolker I think the `-` creates some problems.  As far as I can tell, if we use `B1`, `B2` etc, the order will be the correct.

Comment: Now I can have the solution to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34341923/707145) which was closed immediately I posted it. Thanks again @akrun for your help.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Yes, on the second try you had a much clearer problem statement which made it seem like not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, though IMO worse, solution is to use the native `stats::relevel` function. However, that only allows you to provide a new **reference** level (see the last line of the source code to `stats:::relevel.factor`), so you need to call it recursively.

```
rev_levels <- gtools::mixedsort(levels(df$f))

for (i in 1:length(rev_levels)) {
  df$f <- relevel(df$f, ref= rev_levels[i])
}

levels(df$f)
[1] "B-1"  "B-2"  "B-9"  "B-10" "B-11"
```

I am mainly posting this solution to show what is, in my mind, a flaw in a base-R function/solution. At a minimum, the function is poorly named. It doesn't truly relevel, it simply re-reference-levels